# Prototype.js Observe Select Change Event without class or id

Tags: select, prototype

i am tring to observe select change event on prototype but i want to make this observe  id or class free, thanks for help. best regards.

```
$$("select").each(function(item){       
    item.observe("change",function(e)
    {           
        degis();            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this:

```
$$('select').each(function(item) {
         Event.observe(item,'change', function(){
            degis(); 
        });
});
```